# Using google places search autocomplete in a rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, google-places-api

I am wanting to use google places autocomplete in a rails form.

I am using rails v5.1.1

I am following this article : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

My application layout has the following :

```
    ...lots of layout code
    <% yield %>

        <!-- this is to yield for additional page specific JS from other external sources -->
        <%= yield :additional_page_js %>

        <%= yield :additional_js %>
</body>
```

Then I have a view called journeys/show.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-6">

<div class="col-xs-6">
<h4>Let's make a new leg</h4>

<%= simple_form_for(leg, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :journey_id,  as: :hidden %>
  <%= f.input  :name,  label: 'Give your leg a name', error: 'A name is mandatory - name it!' , hint: 'Something friendly...' %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :origin do |p| %>
        <%= p.input :name ,  label: 'Origin', error: 'An origin is mandatory - where did you begin?' , hint: 'Where did you begin?', :input_html => { :id => "pac-input", :class => "controls" } %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :destination do |n| %>
        <%= n.input :name ,  label: 'Destination', error: 'A destination is mandatory - where did you end up?' , hint: 'Where did you end up?'%>
    <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit , "Lets go!" %>
<% end %>

</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">

  <div id="origin_map"></div>

</div>
</div>

<%= content_for :additional_page_js do %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "controllers/journeys/journeys" %>
<% end %>

<%= content_for :additional_js do %>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAP927IOgIj5GshStjMVfGTfMzHj2Dr1uo&libraries=places&callback=initMapAutocomplete"></script>
<% end %>
```

Note that the `content_for`  'additional_page_js' yield has the following content (which is journeys.js):

```
 function initMapAutocomplete() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('origin_map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
      }
```

The `content_for` additional_js has the following content :

The css for journeys.css has the following:

```
 #description {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #infowindow-content .title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #infowindow-content {
        display: none;
      }

      #map #infowindow-content {
        display: inline;
      }

      .pac-card {
        margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #pac-container {
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: 12px;
      }

      .pac-controls {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 11px;
      }

      .pac-controls label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      #title {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 6px 12px;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
```

When the page loads - the pac-input field does not show - infact it is not even in the generated HTML at all:

```
<%= p.input :name ,  label: 'Origin', error: 'An origin is mandatory - where did you begin?' , hint: 'Where did you begin?', :input_html => { :id => "pac-input", :class => "controls" } %>
```

I get no javascript errors, and I get no rails errors in the server log.

If I remove the javascript from journeys.js - the original form field shows up working just fine. I believe the line which is causing the field to 'disappear' is this line from journeys.js :

```
 var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
```

Please can somebody help me get this google places search autocomplete field working!

Comment: Don't know much about front end but isn't a `div` required for yeilding `additional_page_js` and `additional_js`?

Comment: don't think so? The js itself loads into the page absolutely fine.

Comment: Oh... alright..

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to have 2 components.

1/ The map div had no size, and therefore didn't show up. By changing the html to give it a size - on page load the map now rendered.

```
<div id="origin_map" style='width: 100%; height: 30rem;'></div>
```

2/ Then I realised that my input field had not disappeared - but instead had been moved on top of the map. By commenting out the line which does this repositioning - I was able to fix my form complete with working google places autocomplete.

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
```